# Why no namespace prepended for function when using namespace directive?

Tags: c++, namespaces, linkage

This c++ file...

```
namespace foo {
    class C {
        void m();
    };
    void f();
}

using namespace foo;

void C::m() {}
void f() {}
```

..Compiles to an object file with these symbols:

```
$ g++ foo.cpp  -c
$ nm foo.o  -C
000000000000000a T f()
0000000000000000 T foo::C::m()
```

Why does `C::m()?` get the namespace prepended, but not `f()`?

(I I instead of `using namespace foo` use `namespace foo {...}` then both names has `foo` prepended).

Comment: As the answer shows you, don't be rash to jump to conclusions when writing questions. If something is surprising, best to be careful in how you approach the seeming contradiction and ask something like "Does linkage differ?" rather than assuming that it does (since in fact linkage has nothing to do with your situation; all involved linkages are external).

Comment: @KerrekSB I updated the title to not make assumptions about the cause. (All too often I mix up linkage, scope and storage allocation when dealing with C++).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `void C::m() {}`, `C::m` is a qualified name, and such a definition always refers to something previously declared. The compiler looks up `C`, finds that `C` is actually `foo::C`, thanks to the *using-directive*, and it takes `void C::m(){}` as the definition of `foo::C::m()`.

When you write `void f() {}`, that's a unqualified name, and it always declares the function in the current namespace, which is the global namespace.